# Constraint between UIButton and UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint, terminate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knzqq.png)I'm new to Swift development and it's been few hours since i'm trying to fix this issue that I am facing. The error is with the constraints. Here's my code below:

---

// My constraints code

```
skipButtonAnchor = skipButton.anchor(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.trailingAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 50)
    
bottomStackAnchor = bottomStack.anchor(nil, left: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: view.trailingAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 125, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 50)
```

---

// I've created function for .anchor like this:

```
func anchor(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0, widthConstant: CGFloat = 0, heightConstant: CGFloat = 0) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

I'm looking forward to seeking some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is "the issue that I am facing"?

Answer (score 0):

*"I'm new to Swift development"* --- since you're new, I ***highly*** recommend using standard constraint syntax until you've learned how constraints and auto-layout work. ***Then*** use a "helper func" if you feel it would be helpful.

Try it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // setup properties for skipButton and bottomStack
    // ...
    // add subviews to bottomStack
    // ...
    
    view.addSubview(skipButton)
    view.addSubview(bottomStack)
    
    skipButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bottomStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // respect safe area
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // constrain skipButton Top / Leading / Trailing (to safe area)
        skipButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        skipButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        skipButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        
        // constrain skipButton Height = 50
        skipButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        
        // constrain bottomStack Leading to Leading (safe-area) + 125
        bottomStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 125.0),

        // constrain bottomStack Trailing / Bottom (to safe-area)
        bottomStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        bottomStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        // constrain bottomStack Height = 50
        bottomStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        
    ])

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)